# Como exibir resultados caso meu select dê falso?

Tags: php, mysql

E estou tendo o seguinte problema, existem duas tabelas POSTS e TOPICOS, um topico tem vários posts, e eu estou exibindo os topicos ordenando pela data mais atual do post do topico, só que ao criar um novo topico ele não exibe na tela porque não tem post, e se eu postar no topico ele exibe na tela porque tem post, e eu queria saber como posso exibir os topicos que não tem posts?
Como eu consigo listar os topicos que não tem posts? Porque o meu JOINN só está trazendo os topicos que tem posts relacionados

```
$sqlTopicos = mysqli_query($conexao, 
        "SELECT topico.titulo, posts.idTopico, slug, posts.dataPost, usuario.usuario, visualizacoes, qtdPosts 
         FROM (SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY dataPost DESC) posts 
         INNER JOIN topico 
            ON posts.idTopico = topico.idTopico
         INNER JOIN usuario
            ON topico.idUsuario = usuario.idUsuario
         WHERE posts.idArea = '$idArea' GROUP BY titulo ORDER BY posts.dataPost DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Faça um **Left Join** entre as tabelas: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp. Ele irá trazer os resultados de Topicos mesmo que não existam Posts associados.

Exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM Topicos t
LEFT JOIN Posts p
ON t.TopicoID=p.TopicoID
ORDER BY t.DataCriacao;
```

Comment: Consegui da seguinte maneira:

Comment: Não apareceu a sua solução, posta novamente.